# Reverse lookup an asp.net routed url

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I cannot find a generic way to get the "real/unrouted" url from an asp.net Routed request.

From

```
http://www.mysite.com/news/today
```

get:

```
http://www.mysite.com/news.aspx?date=today
```

My code loooks like:

```
var currentUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
//if url routing is used
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData!=null)
{
    currentUrl = ???            
}
```

I tried with `GetVirtualPath` but sometimes it return nulls, for example with [Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETFriendlyUrlsCleanerURLsEasierRoutingAndMobileViewsForASPNETWebForms.aspx)

```
Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Route.GetVirtualPath(Request.RequestContext,Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find this solution that seems to work in every situation:

```
var currentUrl = Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
if (Page.RouteData != null)
{
    if (Page.RouteData.Route!=null)
    {
        var virtualPathData = Page.RouteData.Route.GetVirtualPath(Request.RequestContext, Page.RouteData.Values);
        if (virtualPathData != null)
        {
            //asp.net routing
            currentUrl = virtualPathData.VirtualPath;
        }
        else
        {
            //only for Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls
            //GetFriendlyUrlFileVirtualPath never returns nulls
            currentUrl = Request.GetFriendlyUrlFileVirtualPath().Replace("~", "");
        }
    }
}
```

For the querystrings use: `Request.QueryString`